# Big test coming up, cant figure this one out: isomorphism between free R-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with a unit. prove that $\operatorname{Hom_R}(R^n,R^m)$ is a free $R$-module of rank $n*m$, please help :]

I thought I'd go with $\operatorname{Hom_R}(R^n,R^m)$ $\cong$ $R^m$ $\cong$ $ R^m \times R^m \times \dots \times R^m$ (n times)

I just don't know how to get there..

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.SE! You are more likely to get help if you show your work thus far. Since I guess you will probably not(?) use *please help!* on your test, you don't seem to have included any of your thoughts yet.

Comment: Update: That's exactly what I had in mind Addar, good work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First prove that $Hom_R(R,R^m)\simeq R^m$. For that you should look at how you can define such $R$-linear a map from the image of $1$.

Then consider a basis of $R^n$ and do the same stuff for $Hom_R(R^n,R^m)$.

Comment: Thanks! just, what do you mean consider a base of $R^n$, how can I show that $\operatorname{Hom_R}(R^n,R^m)$ $\cong$ $\operatorname{Hom_R}(R,R^m)$ X $\operatorname{Hom_R}(R,R^m)$ $X...X$ $\operatorname{Hom_R}(R,R^m)$ (n times)?

Comment: If $f:X_1\times...\times X_n\rightarrow Y$ and if $i_k:X_k\rightarrow X_1\times...\times X_n$ is the injection of the $k$-th component, $f$ is completely determined by the data of the $(f\circ i_k)_{k=1,...,n}$. This is the same as what you did with $n=1$, but this time considering the basis $(1,0,...,0)$, ... , $(0,...,0,1)$.